Mocking an observable with jest
I want to mock this
 getOverlayMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.overlaySubject.asObservable();
  }

I used this getOverlayMessage: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue
but getting this error TypeError: this.messageService.getOverlayMessage(...).subscribe is not a function

mockResolvedValue is for returning a promise. Don't mock observables (in general don't mock what you don't own, and don't mock basic collections etc.), return a real one using of or from (or via a subject as I do in https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/16/async-angular-tests.html).

mockResolvedValue is for returning a promise. Don't mock observables (in general don't mock what you don't own, and don't mock basic collections etc.), return a real one using of or from
getOverlayMessage: of({});

